# Correct way to block non logged in users from WordPress

Tags: wordpress

```
add_action('init','block_non_logged_in_users');
function block_non_logged_in_users(){
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] !='https://example.com/wp-login.php'){
        die('Not logged in!');
    }
}
```

Is the code above ideal way to turn a WP site into a private company intranet? Where only logged in user can access all pages/full site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this, but I would use the global `$pagenow`

```
add_action( 'init', 'block_non_logged_in_users' );
function block_non_logged_in_users() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && 'wp-login.php' !== $pagenow ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You must be logged in to view this site.', 'textdomain' ), 'Not Logged In' );
    }
}
```